# Error initializing cordova class not found

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

here is my index.html.its shows "error initializing cordova class not found " when runing.

```
   <html>
   <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" type="text/css"  
  media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile.config.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>

  </head>
   <body>

     hello

  </body>

  </html>
```

but all the files are available in js and css folder..

im developing this app on eclipse environment..cannot find config.xml which is mention on the post that is similar to my problem.

Comment: check the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934974/error-initilizing-cordova-class-not-found

Comment: please specify more about your development environment.  this is really important.  however i made you an answer for the generic inclusion method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your project.  You have to be specific, but if you are compiling with phonegap build, your cordova.js file do not have to be in your project, it will be included at build.

You have to do this:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

If you are running some sort of other setup you have to mention which.

Comment: His question isent specified weather he uses build, eclipse or... So you are not correct @anand4tech.

Comment: we can keep cordova.js (not jar file) at any where in our project (can we?) we only need to create a reference in HTML file so @Danial how can you write this( if build is compiling with phonegap build)?

Comment: There are different ways of compiling your peoject with phonegap.  If you use phonegap build its without eclipse, and is probaly with phonegap CLI command line.  However it can also be done with a simple zip folder.  The include file "cordova" in any of the 2 mentioned, is included on the fly in phonegap build.

Comment: http://phonegap.com/install/ will show u how you to this.  This is a 100% command line way of using phonegap.  No other programs is required.  Notepad will do if thats how you code ;)

Comment: ok @Daniel, you may b right , I have used eclipse environment for phonegap.

Comment: Ah well i never did use Eclipse, and in your situation things are different.  If you are using a more "Dreamweaver" way as an example, the cordova.js will be included on the fly while compiling the app.  :)